# Spring websocket send message from async method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using spring websocket 4.2.4 with sockjs and stomp and i am trying to send a message from the server to all the subscribers in an async task with no luck

my class is:

```
public class MyClass{
    private timer;
    public MyClass(){
        this.timer = new Timer();
    }

    @Async
    public void myMethod(){
        timer.schedule(new MyReminder(), 1000);
    }

    @Async
    private class MyReminder extends TimerTask{

        @Autowired
        SimpMessagingTemplate messageingTemplate;

        @Override
        public void run(){
            messageingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/subscribers","message");
        }
    }
}
```

but the subscribers dont get the message

any help? what did i do wrong :(

*** EDIT ***

my message broker:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){ 
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/myApp"); 
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/myApp");
}
```

and when i subscribe:

```
subscribe("myApp/someRoute")
```

thanks!!

** Edit 2: **

thanks for the help i fix the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but over Broker destination.

Share, please, your `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`.

Typically we do this:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app/")
            .enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
}
```

Where all those `/app/` destinations won't be treated by Broker. You can subscribe to them only in case of `@SubscribeMapping` - the request-reply scenario from the client initiative.

Your task is fully fits to the publish-subscribe story - `topic` in terms of STOMP.

There fore your subscribers (clients) should be subscribed to some topic on the broker and after that you can simply send message to it.

Comment: public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){ config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/myApp"); config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/myApp");};;;;;;;;; and when i subscribe: subscribe("myApp/someRoute")

Comment: Please, move such a comment to your question as an edit. It's very difficult to follow up with the code in the comments.